# The average of 11 results in 50

Tags: average

The average of 11 results in 50.If the average of first six results is 48 and that of last six 51,the sixth result is?

Answer (score 4):

We have the following system of equations:

$$x_1+\cdots+x_{11}=50\cdot11 \tag{1}$$
$$x_1+\cdots+x_{6}=48\cdot6 \tag{2}$$
$$x_6+\cdots+x_{11}=51\cdot6 \tag{3}$$

Adding (2) and (3), we obtain: $$x_1+\cdots+2x_6+\cdots +x_{11}=6\cdot(48+51)=6\cdot99.$$

Substituting in (1), $$x_6+50\cdot11=6\cdot99 \implies x_6=44.$$